# Using SQL Server "LEFT" function result in poor performance when running Batch data than without it

Tags: c#, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ado.net

While executing / processing batch dealer vehicles data using VIN, I noticed the performance was terribly slow. After some benchmark testings, I found that if I use the T-SQL function `LEFT`, performance suffers but if I don't use it, it works okay.

Without the T-SQL function `LEFT`, I end up with an average of 73 car dealers per minute.  But with `LEFT`, I end up with an average of 5 or 6 car dealers per minutes.

So what's the problem and what's my workaround to the problem? Thanks.

```
using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(this._dbConnectionString))
{
    using (var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        sqlAsk = "";
        sqlAsk += " SELECT Year, Make, Model, Style AS Trim, Squish_Vin AS SquishVin, '' AS VehicleId FROM ED_SQUISH_VIN_V3_90 ";
        //@@sqlAsk += " WHERE @parmVehicleSquishVin = Squish_VIN ";
        sqlAsk += " WHERE @parmVehicleSquishVin LIKE LEFT(Squish_VIN, 9) ";

        dbCommand.CommandText = sqlAsk;
        dbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@parmVehicleSquishVin", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "Squish_VIN").Value = squishVin;

        if (dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) { dbConnection.Close(); }

        dbConnection.Open();

        using (var dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any index on column Squish_VIN?

Comment: Changing your `LIKE LEFT(Squish_VIN, 9)` to `= LEFT(Squish_VIN, 9)` should yield some benefit.

Comment: It seems very odd to use `LIKE` with the vin (or a part of the vin) on the right hand side; does the vin ever contain wildcards? Or is it the *parameter* that might contain wildcards? or are there actually no wildcards here *at all* ?

Comment: @nhrobin - the Squish_VIN does have index and it is up to date daily.

Comment: @JefferyKhan - I tried that and there was no differences.

Comment: @MarcGravell - No wildcard on this one.  Should have been = LEFT(Squish_VIn, 9) but it had no effect on the performance.

Comment: If you usually filter on 9 characters, you can create a calculated, persisted, indexed column based on that formula - it will update automatically, but will work with the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a function on column in the where clause any index on that column doesn't take any effect that means that index has no use. You can write the query a little bit differently to remove the use of LEFT e.g.

```
  sqlAsk += " SELECT Year, Make, Model, Style AS Trim, Squish_Vin AS SquishVin, '' AS VehicleId FROM ED_SQUISH_VIN_V3_90 ";
        //@@sqlAsk += " WHERE @parmVehicleSquishVin = Squish_VIN ";
        sqlAsk += " WHERE Squish_VIN like '"+squishVin+"%'";
```

This query should give the exact same result but without using the LEFT function. You don't need to use any parameter in this case

Comment: Nice!!  It works great!  It performed on par as the one with "WHERE @parm... = Squish_VIN".  It works on par just the same with the SqlParameter as well.  I have to use SqlParameter to avoid sql injection attack.  :-)

Comment: Keep in mind, if you stick a wildcard on the left side (the opposite of where nhrobin put it), it will not use the index (as it can't drill down through the b-tree).  nhrobin's comments about functions in the where clause also pertain to functions as scalars in the select -- the query engine will execute the function for each record in the resultset.